# Setting TextView in Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, textview

I try to set TextView on a dialog that have different layout but the text on the TextView doesnt change. I use that code for this purpose:

```
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    EditText et=(EditText)dialog.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    dosyaAdi=et.getText().toString();

    TextView txv=(TextView) dialog.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.header);
    txv.setText(parametre);


    if(dosyaIslemi){
    generateFeatures kayit=new generateFeatures(this,dosyaAdi);
    }
    else{
    generateFeatures kayit=new generateFeatures(this,dosyaAdi);
    }
    sm.registerListener(this, myAccelerometer,50000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with dialog.setTitle(text); ?

Just use:

```
dialog.getDialog().setTitle("Title here");
```

Comment: Well that's very useful... At least post your whole code so that we can have a look at it...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: ok, i've found setTitle but when i try to do that title never shows up in the opened dialog.